# Don't allow new user, if a user has already logged in

Tags: php, session

```
error_log('my test');   
if(isset($_SESSION["userName"])){
    // some user is present CHECK AND ALLOW THE LOGIN.      
    // Another user has already logged in. so check if the last session activity is more than the SESSIONTIMEOUT value.
    $idleTime = (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVE_TIME'])/60;    
    $idleTime=9;$sessionTimeOut=10;
        if($idleTime<$sessionTimeOut)  {    
            print("*****1*****");       
            $existingUser=$_SESSION["userName"];
            // IDLE TIME IS LESSTHAN THE SESSIONTIMEOUT SO ONLY ALLOW IF IT IS AN OLD USER
                if(strcasecmp( $existingUser, $name ) == 0){
                    print("*****2*****");       
                    $_SESSION["userName"] = $name;
                    $_SESSION["ipaddr"] = $ipaddr;
                    $_SESSION["type"] = $type;
                    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVE_TIME'] = time();
                    updateUserInfo($name,$ipaddr,$type);
                    $url ="./PHome.php" ;
                //  header("Location: $url");
                }   else {
                    print("*****3*****");   
                    // IDLE TIME IS LESSTHAN THE SESSIONTIMEOUT AND new user, SO don't allow
                    $url ="./Login.html" ;

                //header("Location: $url?error=duplicateErr");                      
                }                                   
        } else {
        print("*****4*****");   
            // IDLE TIME IS MORE than sessionTimeOut, SO NEW SECOND USER HAS LOGGED IN
            $_SESSION["userName"] = $name;
            $_SESSION["ipaddr"] = $ipaddr;
            $_SESSION["type"] = $type;
            $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVE_TIME'] = time();
            updateUserInfo($name,$ipaddr,$type);
            $url ="./PHome.php" ;
        // header("Location: $url");
        }       
} else {
print("*****0*****");   
error_log("errors occured");
    // No user is present So Log in 
    $_SESSION["userName"] = $name;
    $_SESSION["ipaddr"] = $ipaddr;
    $_SESSION["type"] = $type;
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVE_TIME'] = time();
    updateUserInfo($name,$ipaddr,$type);
    $url ="./PHome.php" ;
    //header("Location: $url");
}
```

// Logic,

First I am checking if the user has already logged in,  if not I am allowing the user to Login,
Now if a second user comes since the session is already set it should not allow the user to login, But this is allowing. 
Test Scenario - Login using Chrome first and then using an IE, a second user is able to log in.
I Can't use a database, as the db is getting locked and the whole application dies.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `$_SESSION` variables are browser specific - if you set a session on one browser you won't be able to read that session on another browser

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. Is there any-option of using an application context.

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it PHP? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Comment: Hi  CynePhoba12, Thanks for your response, I have checked and it is browser specific.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not sure if you are trying, to stop a same "user" from "same ip" to login is different, but if you want to stop multiple logins in same user this can be the technique

1. Add a field in DB beside the user
2. On login turn it to 1 (You should keep an inactivity timer though to make it 0 after some hours/minutes)
3. While login just add a statement to check if that field is 0 or 1

Comment: Hi Thanks for a quick response, but cant use database.Is there an option of using application context, which is unique.